# Why is all my html highlighted grey in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I just downloaded the new version of WebStorm -- 2016.3.2. For some reason all my HTML tags are highlighted grey.

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this? I've tried looking around in the settings and I posted on the forums too.

**Edit** The problem persists even with all the html styling disabled. [image]

**Edit 2** Even with highlighting set to none it still happens [image]

Comment: That's a **standard** background color for HTML tag. Use another color schema (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colros & Fonts`) or adjust current one to your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add new **Schema** in `Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | HTML` by hitting `Save As...`

[image]

And now you can uncheck **Background** configuration for removing it or change the color.